# Cygwin command through java application on windows

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, cygwin, nutch

1. I am working with nutch 1.9 on windows using cygwin and it works well.
2. Already asked [How to run nutch 1.9 in eclipse on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933941/how-to-run-nutch-1-9-in-eclipse-on-windows) but not getting any answer yet.
3. Is there any way to run cygwin command through java program?
4. I created a script file and tried to execute from batch file using cygwin bash, but it cause "file does not exists" for storing crawled data.

**print.sh**

> *#!/bin/bash 
>
>   cd /cygdrive/c/cygwin/home/apache-nutch-1.9/
>   
>  bin/crawl urls/ crawlresult/ http://localhost:8983/solr/test 1*

**sample.bat**

> *C:\cygwin\bin\bash C:\Users\user\Desktop\print.sh*

**Error**

> *Fetcher: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/apache-nutch-1.9/crawlresult/segments/crawl_generate
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.j
>   ava:190)*

I can run nutch command from cygwin terminal, but fails when running script file as above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to invoke cygwin thorugh java shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468685/how-to-invoke-cygwin-thorugh-java-shell)